# Why can't I pull information on this video with an application access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So if I go to the Facebook Graph API Explorer and paste in the following:

> 653851844748299?fields=from,permalink_url,id

[image]

Why do I only get a valid result if I use a user or page access token?

Why do I get an error if I use an application access token?

Going to `https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=653851844748299` shows the video exists (though you do have to be logged in to see it).

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, application tokens are intended for use "to modify and read the app settings" and to "to publish Open Graph actions".

They are of limited other use, in part because their ability to modify the application settings makes them rather more dangerous than an individual user/page's token.

By preventing them from being very useful outside of their intended use, it's a lot less likely you'll leak one to the client.

> Some user data that would normally be visible to an app that's making a request with an user access token isn't always visible with an app access token.
>
> <sup>(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens)</sup>